# Calling/Testing Web APIs in iOS app

Tags: ios, mysql, objective-c, swift, xcode

I am currently making my first iOS app in Swift.  My web developer has sent me APIs for making calls for each method in the MySQL database table.

How do I use these web APIs in my mobile app to access the database? 
Do I need to create a REST API or can I call these APIs directly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well obviously the Database and API has to be running on a web server some where. Then from your iOS application you would just be calling a web url to fetch data. For example:

```
 mydomain.com/api/v1/getUsers
```

Which should then ideally return results in Json or XML or some format. And you use your programming skills to display that data in application.

Comment: Should I create one class that makes all these calls to the various methods?

Comment: I think it would be good to have once class handle the API calls and return JSON or whatever format. You can have another one to parse the data and return a dictionary or something. But basically once the API call class returns your data you can handle it in the view class.